# Setting $options.template in component created hook - migrating to vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am in the process of migrating a large application from Vue 2 to Vue 3 by using the Vue compat build. In Vue 2 we had a component that accepted a template from its parent as a prop which was then set using this.$options.template in the created lifecycle hook e.g.

```
  created() {
    this.$options.template = this.compiledTemplate;
  }
```

Doing this while using the Vue compat build (3.2.47) results in a warning stating 'Component is missing template or render function.' and the component does not render. Has anyone come across this issue while upgrading Vue?

Have tried swapping it out to render a function using Vue.compile but no joy there.

Comment: do you happen to be using the runtime-only version of Vue?  the [docs](https://vuejs.org/api/options-rendering.html#template) have a note that `options.template` can only be used with full runtime+compiler version.

Comment: Can you add the full component? If you for instance have an additional `setup` function, this might lead to this kind of warnings as it is called before `created`.

Comment: Not using the runtime version using vue.esm-browser, full template is:

````const pageEditArea = {
  name: 'page-edit-area',
  props: ['compiledTemplate'],
  created() {
        this.$options.template = this.compiledTemplate;
  }
};````

Comment: Then you should use the runtime version, otherwise it will not work as mentioned by @yoduh

Comment: How does a compiled template look like? How should someone know, without a [example]?